# MYSQL Insert at start of Value Where Columns 2 equals

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a query to insert `"/2/3/"` at the start of values in column `"Value"` where the values inside column `"attribute_id"` equals `"703"`. I know basic MYSQL but having some issues structuring this.So, any help is appreciated.

Comment: post what you have tried so far and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE table_name SET value=CONCAT('/2/3',value) WHERE attribute_id = 703
N.B:Replace table_name with the name of your table

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table
SET value = '/2/3/' + value
WHERE attribute_id = 703
```

(Replace `table` with the name of your table)

Comment: Okay that didnt seem to work, it has messed up the table instead, it now has changed all values to remove the .jpg and add nothing at the start so where it was 1308.jpg it is now just 1308 :s

Comment: The above SQL would not remove anything, only add '/2/3/' to the start of values in the column `value` where the attribute_id is equal to `703`.

Comment: :s it seems to have removed them though this was the exact query:
UPDATE mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar
SET value = '/2/3/' + value
WHERE attribute_id = 703